# Compare values taken from database and code Yii

Tags: php, sql, yii

Im trying to compare the number that i got from user and the number that is stored in the database.

basically, i'm doing a reward system, where user that reaches a certain amount of points will be given a badge. right now, what i'm doing is, the code will calculate the points that the user have and send it to a function that has an if else to compare the points and the value for each badge.

what i want to do now is, make it simpler by putting the value for each badge inside a db so that next time, i can just update the db and not update the codes. Below is what i'm doing right now.

```
//check total points that the user has
public function totalPointsValue($userId) {

    $value = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('sum(totalPoints) as pointsSum')
        ->from('fndn_UserTotal')
        ->where('userId =:id', array(':id'=>$userId))
        ->queryRow();

    $totalPoints = $value['pointsSum'];

    return $totalPoints;
}

//checks whether the user points is enough for a badge
public function checkEligable($userId){

    $points = $this->totalPointsValue($userId);

    //is not eligable for a badge
    if ($points <100){
        error_log(" $userId has less than 100 points. Number of points is $points ");
    }

    //eligable for the over 100 points badge
    elseif ($points > 100 && $points <1000){
        error_log(" $userId is eligable for over-100 badge. Number of points is $points ");


    }

    //eligable for the over 1000 points badge
    elseif ($points > 1000 && $points <2000){
        error_log(" $userId is eligable for over-1000 badge. Number of points is $points ");


    }

    //eligable for the over 2000 points badge
    else {
        error_log(" $userId is eligable for over-2000 badge. Number of points is $points ");


    }

    error_log(print_r($points, true), 3, 'debug.log');

}
```

i want to make it so that the code, checks the value inside the db and compares it with $points. Below is my badge db.

==============

```
id         badgeName        requiredPoints
1          over100            100
2          over500            500
3          over1000           1000 
4          over2000           2000
```

so,lets say the user has 600 points, it will check which badge the user is entitled to receive. if the $points > requirePoints, it will grant the user a badge.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have table & model name Badge.

EDIT:
If you just want only badge level that is nearest the point user gets

```
function getBadgesOfUser($points){
        $achive_badges = "";
        $badges = CHtml::listData(Badge::model()->findAll(array(
            'order'=>'requiredPoints', // ASC
            'condition'=>'requiredPoints>=:rqp',
            'params'=>array('rqp'=>$points))), 'badgeName', 'requiredPoints');

        if(count($badges)>0){
          //php 5.4
            $achive_badges = array_keys($badges)[0]; // I don't use array_shift in this line because it would cause the warning raising in some cases.

           //following for PHP 5.3
           $temp = array_keys($badges); $achive_badges = $temp[0];

        }
        return $achive_badges;
}
```

I use comparison operator to sort in query, it means that the `requirePoints` column's data type must be numeric (int, decimal, etc.)

Comment: i haven't tried this code but i have a question, what is the min and max for. don't quite understand it @Telvin

Comment: Each badge level requires the standard of earning points table (min-max) that a user might earn to get that badge. For example: the badge 'over500' requires min=500 & max=1000, max = 1000 because your table record indicated that 1000 is next level point of badge 500

Comment: i didn;'t saw your output before. lets say the point is 750, i dont want array with 2 values. i just want the over500 badge, not the over100 badge.

Comment: thanks @Telvin . will try it out. by the looks of it, it should work, except you put the model name as City,heh. will give an update.

Comment: the code didn't work. i changed it according to my database, still didn;t work. but it also didn't display any errors. care to help?

Comment: I just pop an example as my idea, some column names which I have written did not match your column names exactly. If you still got trouble in copying my code, I would correct it like what your sample was. I have updated it again, just check in my answer.

Comment: an error is showing " PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' ....." the [0] is causing an error" the [0] is causing this @Telvin .

Comment: (1). var_dump $badges to see what it returned: array or empty?
(2). I accecced first element of result array $achive_badges by [0].
I am using PHP 5.4, maybe the error occured because you are using lower php version such as 5.3, just do by standard way like what I have updated in my answer